# Why does my MVC binding stop working when I assign a nested model to a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have code something like this contrived example in my MVC 4 razor view:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.NestedModel.Count; i++)
{                                                    
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => modelModel.NestedModel[i].Id)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.NestedModel[i].SomeProperty)              
}
```

In which case everything works fine for me  However, I wanted to tidy this up a little as the real world example is a little more involved.  So I tried this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.NestedModel.Count; i++)
{                        
    var nestedModel = Model.NestedModel[i];

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => nestedModel.Id)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => nestedModel.SomeProperty)                     
}
```

This time the code doesn't appear to bind properly.  The rendered html looks the same in terms of name and id attributes that are generated.

Is there any reason why I cannot not assign the nested model to a variable and then use it in this way?

Comment: Inspect the html you generate in each case. They are different (the second one will not have the indexers necessary for binding to a collection). If you do want to 'tidy this up' then you could look at using an `EditorTemplate`

Comment: well use `foreach` to make even cleaner `@foreach (var nest in Model.NestedModel)` & access `model=>nest.Id`  . cheers

Comment: @supercool, using a `foreach` loop will not generate the correct html for binding to a collection (at least not without some really ugly workarounds). It must be a `for` loop or an `EditorTemplate`

Comment: ofcourse it will not you are not indexing helpers

Comment: ooh i see @StephenMuecke . any reason all it does is looping like for i.e different fashion .

Comment: @supercool, A `foreach` will evaluate the expression `nest` and generate `<input name="nest" ... />` - i.e. all controls will have the same `name` and `id` attributes (invalid html) without the indexers - which is what OP's second code example is doing. In order to bind to a collection, it must be `<input name="NestedModel[0].Id" .../>`, `<input name="NestedModel[1].Id" .../>` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect the html you are generating you will see that they are not the same. Your first code block generates html like

```
<input name="NestedModel[0].Id" id="NestedModel_0__Id" .../>
<input name="NestedModel[1].Id" id="NestedModel_1__Id" .../>
```

The second one will generate html like

```
<input name="nestedModel.Id" id="nestedModel_Id" .../>
<input name="nestedModel.Id" id="nestedModel_Id" .../>
```

The second generates invalid html (duplicate `id` attributes) but more importantly generates a `name` attribute which has no relationship to your model.

If you wanting to *"to tidy this up a little"*, you should consider using a custom `EditorTemplate` for the type. For example if the model is

```
public class MyModel
{
  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
  ....
}
```

create a partial in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyModel.cshtml` (note the name must match the name of the type

```
@model yourAssembly.MyModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
....
```

and then in the main view you can just use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NestedModel)
```

The `EditorFor()` method accepts both a single object and `IEnumerable<T>` and will correctly generate the html for you.